# A safe way of 'overwriting'/'forcing' a certain implicit resolution

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a custom formatter (say `MyFormat`) for `org.joda.DateTime` which provides a `Format[org.joda.DateTime]`.

Play provides a default formatter for the same class in the `play.api.libs.json` package.

I would like to use `MyFormat` across my application, and not the one Play provides. I have done this through explicit imports/mixins which does the trick, however during changes or omissions when these get removed, serialization defaults to the Play formatter and I end up with runtime errors. This seems very error prone.

Ultimately I would like for my code not to compile if there is no `MyFormat` for `org.joda.DateTime` in scope whenever one is required.

Is there a nice and safe way of doing this?

Comment: I think the only thing you can do to prioritize your own implicit is to move it into the current scope of where it is used (which isn't good in your case because duplication). Can't you extend Format and work with that new type ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, but neither of them will be exactly what you want. The crux of the problem is that Scala will look for implicits within related companion objects. For example, if it needs to find an implicit `Format[DateTime]`, it will look within the companion object of `Format` and the companion object of `DateTime`. In this case, there is an implicit def within `Format` that will produce the desired (or in your case, undesired) `Format[DateTime]` and there's nothing you can do to get rid of it, short of forking and hacking Play.

---

**Workaround 1**: Create an object with your custom formatters, and import it globally:

```
package my.project

object Formats {
    implicit val dateTimeFormat: Format[DateTime] = ???
}
```

(in other files)

```
import my.project.Formats._
```

The `Format[DateTime]` imported into a local scope will supersede the one resolved from the `Format` object. However, you can't prevent your code from compiling without it (unless you have some sort of scalastyle rule or something that requires the import).

---

**Workaround 2**: Create a wrapper for `DateTime` with it's own `Format`, and give it an implicit conversion to `DateTime`.

```
case class MyDateTime(dt: DateTime) {
    implicit def toDateTime: DateTime = dt
}

object MyDateTime {
    implicit val fmt: Format[MyDateTime] = ???
    implicit def fromDateTime(dt: DateTime): MyDateTime = MyDateTime(dt)
}
```

This is not a complete example, but an idea as  to how to implement this. `DateTime` can be swapped with `MyDateTime` is most places, however it may require other implicits revolving around `MyDateTime`. For example, when I tried using this with Anorm, I needed an implicit `ToStatement[MyDateTime]`, and probably a few others--so that's the obvious disadvantage. However, this would explicitly avoid using the default `Format[DateTime]`.